# C++ Lua Getting Value From Lua Table

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table, lua-api

I am trying to get values from a Lua table. This is what I have written in Program.cpp:

```
lua_State* lua = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(lua);
luaL_dofile(program->getLuaState(), "Script.lua");

lua_getglobal(lua, "table");
lua_pushstring(lua, "x");
lua_gettable(lua, -2);
printf("%i", lua_tonumber(lua, -1));
```

And I wrote this in Script.lua:

```
table = {x = 12, y = 32}
```

The problem is that this only writes 0 in the console. I have checked that the lua file is loading correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `%i` to `%g`. `lua_tonumber` returns a float or double, not an int.

Comment: Oh my god, I feel so stupid now. I literary tried to solve this for more than 40 minutes. Thanks alot